# Java NPE with .split

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm fairly new with Java, (and this site) so I'm not sure what to do with this "issue"...
I'm not sure whether to put my entire code in this or not...So I'll just put what I think is causing the issue. The program compiles perfectly, except when I try to run it. That's when I get a Null Pointer Exception at line 96. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LicensePlateGeneratorTemplate extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  private JTextArea txtOutput;
  private JTextField txtNumPlates;
  private JButton btnDisplay;
  private JLabel lblTitle, lblInstruction;
  private PrintWriter output;
  private String letters, numbers, fileName;
  private int randomLetter, randomNumber, numPlates;
  private String [] a, b ;
  private String [] lttrArray, nmbrArray;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

new LicensePlateGeneratorTemplate();

}    
  public LicensePlateGeneratorTemplate() throws IOException{
    //label thast contains number of licence plates generated
    txtNumPlates = new JTextField();
    txtNumPlates.setBounds(320, 60, 28, 28);
    lblInstruction = new JLabel("How many license plates would you like to generate?");
    lblInstruction.setBounds(15, 60, 300, 28);

//A random number generator in the action performed method should allow you to select a random letter from the letters String
//then a random number from the numbers String

String letters = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Z";
String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0";

lttrArray = letters.split (",");
nmbrArray = numbers.split (",");

System.out.println(lttrArray[20] + lttrArray [10]);
System.out.println(nmbrArray[3]+ nmbrArray [5]);

fileName = "licensePlates.txt";
output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

lblTitle = new JLabel();
lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 28));
lblTitle.setText("License Plate Generator");
lblTitle.setBounds(30, 10, 400, 50);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);

//JTextArea
txtOutput = new JTextArea();
txtOutput.setBounds(60, 150, 275, 196);
txtOutput.setEditable(true);

//generate button properties
btnDisplay = new JButton();
btnDisplay.setText("Generate");
btnDisplay.setBounds(150, 100, 100, 40);
btnDisplay.setFocusable(true);
btnDisplay.addActionListener(this);

//add components to the panel
panel.add(btnDisplay);
panel.add(txtOutput);
panel.add(lblTitle);
panel.add(lblInstruction);
panel.add(txtNumPlates);

//frame properties
setContentPane(panel);
setSize(400, 400);
setTitle("License Plate Generator");
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
  {
    if (e.getSource() == btnDisplay)
    {
     //change number user inputs into a int value
      int userNum = Integer.parseInt(txtNumPlates.getText ());

 for (int k = 0; k <= userNum; k ++)
  {//number of licence places that are being made

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)//loop for letters produced
    {
      int randLtr = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((24 - 0) + 1));
      a [i]  = lttrArray [randLtr];
      output.println (a[i]);
      txtOutput.insert(a[i] + "\n", 0);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)//loop for number produced
    {
      int randNum = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((9 - 0) + 1));  
      b [j] = nmbrArray [randNum];
      output.println (b[j]);
      txtOutput.insert(b[j] + "\n", 0);
    }
    output.close();//closes fileWriter
  }//end of userNum loop
}//end of e.getsource
  }  
}
```

Edit: Added full code.

Comment: Which line is giving you the NullPointerException?

Comment: Please post the stack trace for your error for better assistance.

Comment: Where are those `lttrArray`, `nmbrArray` variables defined ?

Comment: To avoid people guessing, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `a [i]  = lttrArray [randLtr];`

Comment: If you're going to quote line numbers, you should add line numbers to your code snippet. StackOverflow will colour them for you. See my example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913295/impossible-npe-being-thrown-java

Answer (score 0):

Since `lttrArray` is clearly non-null (unless you're assigning it as `lttrArray = null` somewhere in the snipped code), I would guess that `a` is null.

Comment: It may be null, if it's a class-member, that is being set in some setter (which is not invoked before the actionevent)

Comment: @kocko OP's code implies that `lttrArray` is not null, with `lttrArray = "A,B,C,...".split(",")`

Comment: But when is the `.split()` operation called ? That's the question - before the actionevent, or not ?

Comment: I understand your point, but the indication was before... of course, that's where an SSCCE is helpful.