# Impossible NPE being thrown (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In this example code a `NullPointerException` is being thrown on line 4.

```
1. private <O,T> void generate(Suggestion suggestion, GeneratorFactory<O, T> generatorFactory) {
2.     final Generator<O, T> generator = generatorFactory.getGenerator(suggestion);
3.     while (generator.hasNext()) {
4.         generator.doGenerate();
5.     }
6.     // post-generate stuff here
7. }
```

It only happens occasionally, but it has happened a few times on a live server, so it's not some kind of "ghost" bug - it definitely needs fixing.

---

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package.SuggestionServiceImpl.generate(SuggestionServiceImpl.java:4)
```

---

Code for GeneratoryFactory:

```
@Override
public synchronized Generator<O, T> getGenerator(final Suggestion suggestion) {
    Generator<O, T> generator = generators.get(suggestion.getId());
    if (generator == null) {
        generator = construct(suggestion); // calls `new Generator()`
        generators.put(suggestion.getId(), generator);
    }
    return generator;
}
```

---

I'm confused by:

- How come we don't get a NPE in the 'if' statement on line 3, if it's `generator` that's null?
- How come the stack trace starts at line 4, and not from a line inside `doGenerate()` if that's where the exception is coming from? (The internals of `doGenerate()` are lengthy and complex - it is possible that an NPE starts here, but why no stack trace?)

---

**Update:**

As an experimental test, I deliberately threw a NPE inside `doGenerate()` [in dev environment] to compare the stack trace with the mystery live one. It does indeed have the anticipated extra stack frame.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: DELIBERATE TEST EXCEPTION
    at package.Generator.doGenerate(Generator.java:71)
    at package.SuggestionServiceImpl.generate(SuggestionServiceImpl.java:4)
```

---

The runtime JVM is:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.1.4-7-144370-1.6.0_26-20110617-2130-linux-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

Comment: could you add some stacktrace please?

Comment: There may be an error **inside** the `doGenerate()` method.

Comment: please post the stacktrace and doGenerate() method.

Comment: @Dariusz if the error in doGenerate() the stacktrace should be come from there.

Comment: nothing is impossible - especially not NullpointerExceptions

Comment: "Impossible is nothing..."

Comment: post your `doGenerate()` method and stacktrace... that helps

Comment: @MarcoForberg what a synch :))

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the code running is the same version as your source?

Comment: May be some other thread caused generator to be null.... do you have more than one thread in your program?

Comment: I'm happy to debug inside `doGenerate()` if that's where the NPE is coming from. What's confusing me is why the stack trace only reports the NPE as coming from the calling class ...

Comment: @pinkpanther *Nothing* can change a `final` local variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah...I din't see that line :)

Comment: Is that the complete trace ?

Comment: That's the top end of the trace. Below it is just some Spring Framework and AOP stuff all the way back to `java.lang.Thread.run()`

Comment: Can `getGenerator` return `null`? If it can, why is there no check for it? Same for `suggestion` and `generatorFactory`

Comment: `getGenerator` should never return null, but posting code for it ...

Comment: @Stewart is `hasNext()` a static method? if it is so, no exception is thrown if even if  `generator` is a null reference

Comment: @SimonC - I'm very sure. It is the most obvious thing to suspect though. As I commented in the answer below, I'm going to add some logging, get that live, wait for it to happen again, and post the result here. I'm willing to eat humble pie if that's what it is :)

Comment: @pinkpanther - `hasNext()` is not static. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you some theoretical options:

1. it may be a mundane thing like a wrong line number reported. For example, due to different versions of binary code and the source code you are looking at;
2. the exception may be happening somewhere else, but you see a severed stacktrace. This could be due to some intervenening code messing with the stacktrace (no magic neededed for this, just plain Java), or the logging framework may be messing it up occasionally;
3. you are hitting an actual bug in JRockit, possibly its JIT. For example, there may be some *locals clearing* in effect which happens out of order.

My suggestion: insert a log statement within the loop, but above the `doGenerate` call. You may also explicitly log the result of `generator != null`. This will help you eliminate any but the most bizarre explanation.

Comment: `locals clearing` is a new term for me - do you mean `ThreadLocal` or something else?

Comment: Presumably severing a stack trace has to be something quite deliberate. It couldn't be done simply by catching and rethrowing an exception, could it?

Comment: No, it's nulling out a local variable to allow its referent to be GC'd. It can legitimately occur after the last usage of the variable.

Comment: I see, so something later in the code is setting `generator` to null, but somehow, due to a JRocket bug, this is happening out of sequence?

Comment: Yes, it involves `Exception#setStackTrace` and is occasionally done to prettify the trace (eliminate excessive slots coming from framework/reflection layer).

Comment: I am voting for #1. 90% is that somehow the code has been changed and NPE is actually thrown from other line. For example from `while (generator.hasNext())`

Comment: @AlexR Yes, that's something we have all seen happen, so it is the number one suspect here, too. That hypothesis is easily falsifiable with my proposed addition of a logging statement.

Comment: I agree that a mis-reported line number is the most likely cause, and I did specifically look into that possibility. Currently I'm fairly sure that my code matches live, but I'm willing to publicly eat humble pie, so I'll look again and post if that's what it is. :-)

Comment: @Stewart It would be better to add the logging statement. Once you see that log entry, you can be dead sure about the nullness of `generator`  before the actual call---with or without the exact line number.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to add logging, get that code live, and wait for it to happen again. I'll be sure to post the results of that back here.

Comment: This happened over a month ago, and the extra logging statements have been live, and the NPE has not repeated yet. I'm going to accept this answer meanwhile, as the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue. It looks like JUnit (or JVM) truncated stacktrace in wrong way. Wrapping whole test method in try/catch and using Exception.printStackTrace() showed the real source of NPE instead of "impossible" location.